# How do I import module from directory in python,linux

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu

I am running a python script however I get the following error;

```
ImportError: No module named 'config.paths'; 'config' is not a package
```

My project folder looks like this

`Hell/
   hen/
      config/
             paths.py
    abc/
      def/
             code.py`

and this project is the directory of my ubuntu system :

```
/home/fisker/workspace/Hell
```

I am trying to execute **code.py**, but It should get **paths.py from config folder**. How do I do this?

I even tried using;

```
PYTHONPATH="/home/fisker/workspace/Hell/:$PYTHONPATH" python code.py
```

and

appending the following code in the beginning of code.py

`import sys 
  sys.path.append('/home/fisker/workspace/Hell')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to transform config to a package in order to import it.

Just create a `__init__.py` file in config directory.

Example:

Hell/
      hen/
                  config/
                               paths.py
                               **init**.py

In your code.py file you will need to:

`from code import what_you_want`